# Error al generar signed bundle (s) con codigo java en android studio

Tags: java, android, bundler

He desarrollado una aplicación en Android Studio con código Java. Al generar el signed bundle (s), obtengo este error: error: C: \ Users \ Desktop \ sc_4 \ app \ src \ main \ res \ layout \ activity_main.xml: 34: AAPT: error: resource menu / menu_barra_main (Also known as. jmssp.pa_jmssp: menu / menu_barra_main) no found. refiriéndose a la botton navigation view que implemento en una de las clases.

dependencia.:

```
implementation  'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

archivo xml.:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
android:id="@+id/navigationViewMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
app:menu="@menu/menu_barra_main" />
```

archivo del menu xml.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_Botones"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_main"
    android:title="Menu" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_Web"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_main2"
    android:title="Pagina Principal" />
</menu>
```

codigo java.:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView =  
findViewById(R.id.navigationViewMain);
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(ne
BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        if(menuItem.isChecked()){
            return true;
        } else{
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.menu_Botones:                    
                    setFragment(homeFragment);
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Principal");
                    return true;
                case R.id.menu_Web:
                    setFragment(home_Web);
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Pagina Web");
                    return true;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

espero haberme expresado correctamente.
gracias de antemano.

Comment: el archivo del menu debe llamarse  menu_barra_main.xml , asegura que asi sea, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a el error presentado

> AAPT: error: resource menu / menu_barra_main (Also known as.
>   jmssp.pa_jmssp: menu / menu_barra_main) no found.

Tu BottomNavigationView hace referencia a un archivo de menu llamado `menu_barra_main.xml`

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
android:id="@+id/navigationViewMain"
...
...
...
app:menu="@menu/menu_barra_main" />
```

El archivo de menu debe llamarse `menu_barra_main.xml` y localizarse dentro del directorio `/menu` que a su vez se debe encontrar dentro del directorio de recursos `/src`

`/src/menu/menu_barra_main.xml`

Comment: Si. El archivo se llama menu_barra_main.xml y esta correctamente localizado. Cuando lo corro en un dispositivo virtual o físico funciona bien. Pero cuando quiero generar el apk filmado me sale ese error.